# The exact meaning of "Enquiries Over $xxx,xxx"

Tags: meaning, british-english, phrase-meaning

I often see "Enquiries Over $xxx,xxx" in real estate ads, e.g. "Enquiries Over $500,000".

Does the "over" literally mean offers should be above the figure (or don't bother approaching the seller), or "around" the figure (i.e. the figure is provided as a guideline, not a minimum)?

Does the same apply to "Negotiate Over"?

*Please note that it is the exact meaning of the phrase I am asking, not enquiry / negotiation tactics.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Enquiries Over $xxx,xxx" means that the seller will not consider offers under the stated amount.  In New Zealand, they apparently take this seriously.  Go [here](http://www.scoop.co.nz/stories/PO0712/S00155.htm) for a story that uses the term about a real estate agent fined for advertising a property at "Enquiries over $380K" when he knew the seller wouldn't let the property go for under $400K.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer with example. I'm in New Zealand :) Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the owner wants offers over the amount x. So don't bother offering anything under x.